# Oracle EXP Error ORA-12704: character set mismatch

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, backup

I need to duplicate a Oracle 11g Express Edition database from one computer to 
another computer.

I tried `exp sys/password FULL=Y FILE=backup.dump` (the idea is to do a imp on the other pc)

But it gaves me the following error:

```
EXP-00008: ORACLE error 12704 encountered
ORA-12704: character set mismatch
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SERVER_ALERT_EXPORT", line 10
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SERVER_ALERT_EXPORT", line 118
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

How can I make a full, complete backup with usernames, passwords, everything to be loaded into another host?

Comment: What version of exp are you trying to use to do the export?

Comment: The character set and national character set of both db are the same? I have found some causes to that error [here](http://ora-12704.ora-code.com/). Anyway you can try to import only your own schemas you need, or you can try to clone the db using RMAN, for example.

Comment: I am using Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0

Comment: Which two dbs? I have that error when trying to make a backup, not even tried to restored it. Anyway... I am tring with RMAN now.. let's see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Anyway, doing some tests, in the log I get this text: `Export done in UTF8 character set and UTF8 NCHAR character set
server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)`. What log text do you get?